# Symfony twig controller route

Tags: symfony, routes, controller, twig

I am begginer and I have little problem.

**I have:**

I have one primary menu with links to Controller main actions (index) and one secondary menu with links to other actions like create / edit / delete.

**My problem is:**

I don't know how to tell twig, that links in primary menu are active when any action in that controller is called.

In secondary menu I have:

```
{% set route_name = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
<a class="{% if route_name == item.route %} active {% endif %}">Link</a>
```

**I have tried:**

I tried to do it with prefixes on Controller, but it didn't worked.

Any hints or tips please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your menu has only 2 nested levels, you can set a `@Route` annotation in the whole controller:

```
/**
 * @Route(path="admin/pegass", name="admin_pegass_")
 */
class PegassController extends BaseController
{
```

For every action in your controller, you just need to set the end of the name and path:

```
/**
 * @Route(name="list_users", path="/list-users")
 */
public function userList()
{
```

Finally, when rendering the first level of your menu, you can use:

```
{% set route_name = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
<a class="{% if route_name[0:13] == 'admin_pegass_' %} active {% endif %}">Link</a>
```

For more complex menus, breadcrumbs are not trivial, it will be easier to create an object representation of it in order to traverse it and perform operations in a more generic way (you can use a bundle like [KnpMenu](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle)).